Why can't TypeScript infer the type of a generic object property in a conditional branch?
I'm trying to write a type-safe function in TypeScript, but I'm running into a type inference issue when narrowing the type of an object property. Here's a minimal example:
type Language = "TYPESCRIPT" | "PYTHON";
type Code<T extends Language> = { lang: T; content: string };

function typecheck<T extends Language>(code: Code<T>) {
  if (code.lang === "TYPESCRIPT") {
    typecheckTS(code); // Error: Argument of type 'Code<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Code<"TYPESCRIPT">'
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}

function typecheckTS(code: Code<"TYPESCRIPT">) {
  // ...
}

(Playground)
TypeScript gives the following error:
Argument of type 'Code<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Code<"TYPESCRIPT">'.
However, when I redefine the Code type using a conditional type with the infer keyword, TypeScript handles the type inference correctly:
type Language = "TYPESCRIPT" | "PYTHON";
type Code<T extends Language> = T extends infer T_ ? { lang: T_; content: string } : never;

function typecheck<T extends Language>(code: Code<T>) {
  if (code.lang === "TYPESCRIPT") {
    typecheckTS(code); // Works fine
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}

function typecheckTS(code: Code<"TYPESCRIPT">) {
  // ...
}

(Playground)
I don't fully understand why TypeScript behaves this way, and while the infer solution works, I find it unintuitive and would prefer a cleaner approach.
Constraints:

Code must remain a generic type and typecheck() must be a generic function.
I want to avoid explicit type casting and let TypeScript handle type inference.

Is there a more intuitive solution to this issue that satisfies these constraints?

Does typecheck need to be a generic function? If not you can write it this way since code is effectively of a discriminated union type. If that meets your needs I'll write an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to clarify the unsatisfied requirement (e.g.,, say "typecheck must be a generic function" instead of just "Code must be a generic type").

It does need to be generic. I edited the question accordingly.

• Do you consider const x: Foo = y to be "explicit type casting"? It's an annotation, not a cast (which would be more like const x = y as Foo). • What do you consider "intuitive"? The problem with Code<T> for generic T is that it's not a discriminated union and that's the only way TS narrows on prop access. If you want to get narrowing on prop access otherwise you need something like a type guard function as shown in the answer below.

Sorry, TS doesn't narrow generic types, you could use a custom type guard. But I like your solution with the infer. It seems that it forces TS to evaluate the generic type to full types' union, so the type guard works fine.
Playground
type Language = "TYPESCRIPT" | "PYTHON";
type Code<T extends Language> = { lang: T; content: string };

const isLang = <T extends Language>(code: Code<Language>, lang: T): code is Code<T> => code.lang === lang;

function typecheck<T extends Language>(code: Code<T>) {
  if (isLang(code, "TYPESCRIPT")) {
    typecheckTS(code); // Error: Argument of type 'Code<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Code<"TYPESCRIPT">'
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}

function typecheckTS(code: Code<"TYPESCRIPT">) {
  // ...
}


Not ideal, but one option is to reconstruct an object with the checked type:
function typecheck<T extends Language>(code: Code<T>) {
    const { lang, content } = code;
    if (lang === "TYPESCRIPT") {
        typecheckTS({ lang, content });
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}

